# QT 4 Designer - How to link a Qtoolbutton/pushbutton to an action

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have recently been working on creating a GUI interface for an application. I decided to use QT4 designer, as it seemed to be an easier means of manipulating the visual portion. I initially created a QPushbutton that would link to some action(for example a message box that says "you have pushed this button"). However after some preliminary (and possibly inaccurate research), I switched it to a Qtoolbutton because apparently it is easier to link an action to it. However, I still have not figured out how to link an action to a button in QTdesigner 4. Is there a way I can do this? Also is there a way I can view the source code behind my GUI? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can't link action to a button in QtDesigner, you do that in code. QtDesigner is used for easy GUI design.

Once you've created GUI in QtDesigner (for example mainwindow with only one pushbutton) you save it as testUI.ui. To convert it to python module (.py) run this line in cmd:

```
pyuic4 -x testUI.ui -o testUI.py
```

now you can view source code of GUI you've created in testUI.py (but that is something that you should not change!!!).

`testUI.py` file you need to import in your main python program, so in code you can link button with some action. Here is example of how to do that(i've allready created testUI.py , in Designer I've named QPushButton "myButton"):

```
import  sys
from PyQt4         import QtGui, QtCore
import testUI # put testUI.py in the same dir as this code

class TestWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = testUI.Ui_MainWindow() # in this and next line you say that you will use all widgets from testUI over self.ui
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
        #so, when you say self.ui.myButton ,that is pushButton in testUI that has name myButton 
        self.ui.myButton.clicked.connect(self.DoSomething)# connect button clicked with action

    def DoSomething(self):
        print "button clicked" #    or message box  or something else

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

if you have any questions feel free to ask

Answer (score -2):

In Qt creator 4.2.0 you can simply add an action in the .cpp file
so after:

```
       ui->setupUi(this);
```

just add:

```
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(buttonClicked()));
```

then create a function "buttonClicked" that you also put in the slot part of your .h file.

You can change the name "pushButton" in the designer if want more explicit names.

Comment: This approach does not link the `QAction` text and icon with the button.